# Index 404 handler error yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Recently I have the site has developed another person, is written in yii2, whenever I try to open the index the handlererror redirects to site/error.php, when passing through actionIndex doesn't found the site(view), I'm new with yii2 and I'm trying to fix that does not get the index.php

```
 public function actionIndex()
        {
            // $this->layout = false;
            return $this->render('index');
        }
```

output of $this is:

```
app\controllers\SiteController Object
(
    [layout] => site
    [enableCsrfValidation] => 1
    [actionParams] => Array
        (
        )

    [id] => site
    [module] => yii\web\Application Object
        (
            [defaultRoute] => site
            [catchAll] => 
            [controller] => app\controllers\SiteController Object
 *RECURSION*
            [_homeUrl:yii\web\Application:private] => 
            [controllerNamespace] => app\controllers
            [name] => My Application
            [version] => 1.0
            [charset] => UTF-8
            [language] => en-US
            [sourceLanguage] => en-US
            [layout] => admin
            [requestedRoute] => 
            [requestedAction] => yii\base\InlineAction Object
                (
                    [actionMethod] => actionIndex
                    [id] => index
                    [controller] => app\controllers\SiteController Object
 *RECURSION*
                    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                )
```

it is much longer, but I can not paste everything here.

I guess it must be a problem with some routes or controller, but i dont know what's the problem

Comment: Hello, I might be able to help you but I need more info. I don't know if you can paste your code here or somewhere else. I can't exactly where is the error from this code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is something wrong with the path of your view. Please, take a look at the guides: [Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html) and [View](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html).

As you can see, there is some conventions about the name of the file and folders. Make sure you have something like the example bellow:

**File**: `controller/MyAwesomeIdController.php`

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\web\Controller;

class MyAwesomeIdController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $myVar = 'value';

        return $this->render('index', [
            'myVar' => $myVar
        ]);
    }
}
```

**File**: `views/my-awesome-id/index.php`

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $myVar string */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = $myVar;
?>
<div class="my-awesome-id-index">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vestibulum tristique diam, sed facilisis tortor ultricies vitae. Ut lectus leo, egestas sit amet luctus vel, luctus eu enim. Maecenas gravida egestas varius. Cras eu congue quam, in mattis enim. Aliquam nec augue nisi. Sed in tincidunt tellus, vel auctor urna. Donec ipsum tortor, pulvinar in luctus nec, tristique in metus. Ut dapibus velit ac mi lobortis finibus.
    </p>
</div>
```